# Организация переписки пользователей

Tags: sql, mysql

Как правильно хранить сообщения? Если теоретически будет много пользователей и соответственно миллионы сообщений, то как их лучше хранить? Все в одной таблице, это не будет тормозить? Имеет ли смысл и будет ли вообще работать, если создавать таблицу для каждой пары пользователей и хранить там их переписку? Т.е. в базе будут миллионы таблиц.

Comment: Для каждого пользователя своя таблица. Может так?

Comment: Создавать для каждого юзера свою таблицу - это дикий ход :)

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте две таблицы:

1. Пользователи (Id, Name)
2. Сообщения (Id, Message, AuthorId, RecipientId)

В первой храните данные о пользователях, во второй само сообщение Message, AuthorId - Id отправителя, RecipientId получателя.

При необходимости можно расширить таблицу Сообщения добавив Id папки в которой расположено сообщение, дату отправки и т.д.

В этом случае у вас будут две таблицы и миллионы записей в них. Чтобы база не разросталась можно ввести ограничения на кол-ко сообщений в ящике, тогда чтобы общаться юзеры будут сами чистить базу.

Comment: Как вариант: 3 таблицы в случае, если вам нужен поиск по содержимому писем:  

>Пользователи (Id, Name)  
 Сообщения (Id, Message, AuthorId, RecipientId)  
 Сообщения_for_fast_search (Id, FunctionFromMessage, FunctionFromAuthorName, FunctionFromRecipientName)  

п.с. Не знаю, как в MySql, а в оракл очень большие таблицы можно разбивать на части (partitions), может в мускуле есть что-то похожее.

Comment: @jmu, а можно поподробнее о Сообщения_for_fast_search и всяких FunctionFrom...? Интересно...

Comment: А на случай "одно сообщение - многим пользователям", таблица 2 примет вид: (Id, Message, AuthorId) и добавим таблицу 3 (MessageID, RecipientID), дабы не дублировать сообщение каждый раз, для каждого получателя.

Comment: @gote для фамилий саундекс (http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Саундекс) и ему подобные. а для сообщений насколько мне известно пишут под свои нужды. гуглить: индексация строк если мне не ошибает память

Comment: Вы как то глубоко углубились и всё усложнили ;)

Comment: если честно это небыло моей задачей, хотел человеку дать пищу для размышлений :)

Answer (score 0):

Ко всему вышеперечисленному добавлю: если вы планируете работать с большим количеством данных, попробуйте PostgreSQL.